# Virtual mailboxes with Postfixadmin + Courier IMAP - Expected mail directories not being generated

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, postfix, courier-imap

I have set-up a mail server with Postfix, and I am currently in the process of creating virtual mailboxes with the help of Postfixadmin. I am using Courier to handle IMAP authentications, and I am having troubles with setting it up properly.

I studied the logs and narrowed down the main problem being IMAP not being able to locate the designated maildirs. That is, the maildirs do not exist.

I am able to solve the problem by manually creating the maildirs that IMAP is expecting, but I dont really see myself having to do this every time I add a mailbox. I would need it to work automatically as soon as I add virtual mailboxes via Postfixadmin.

Am I missing something?

Here are some relevant information:

Postfixadmin uses a MySQL database to look up mailboxes, and the description of the relevant table is as follows:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| username   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| password   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| maildir    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| quota      | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| local_part | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| domain     | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |       |
| created    | datetime     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| modified   | datetime     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| active     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1                   |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

And here is a sample record:

```
username = user@domain.com
password = [hashed password here]
name = User 01
maildir = user@domain.com
quota = 0
local_part = user
domain = domain.com
created = 2012-08-17 07:52:01
modified = 2012-08-17 07:52:01
active = 1
```

(domain.com is simply a dummy for the purpose of this question. I am using a registered domain with a working MX record.)

Here are the contents of my `/etc/courier/authmysqlrc`

```
MYSQL_SERVER 127.0.0.1
MYSQL_USERNAME [omitted]
MYSQL_PASSWORD [omitted]
MYSQL_DATABASE [omitted]
MYSQL_USER_TABLE mailbox
MYSQL_LOGIN_FIELD username
MYSQL_NAME_FIELD name
MYSQL_CRYPT_PWFIELD password
#MYSQL_CLEAR_PWFIELD     password
MYSQL_MAILDIR_FIELD maildir
MYSQL_QUOTA_FIELD concat(quota,'S')
MYSQL_HOME_FIELD        '/home/vmail'
MYSQL_UID_FIELD '5000'
MYSQL_GID_FIELD '5000'
```

(I have created the necessary UNIX user ang group for this, with the proper UID:GID of 5000:5000 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by removing our domain from `mydestinations` and allowing Postfixadmin to send a welcome message upon creation. Apparently the mail directories are created when the email arrives, so the sending of welcome message takes care of it.